# Prometheus auto discovery K8s

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Can someone guide the configuration for auto discover for K8s. The Prometheus server is outside of the cluster. I tried [Service Discovery With Kubernetes](https://movio.co/en/blog/prometheus-service-discovery-kubernetes/) and someone mentioned in this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-developers/kll2itGFkVg)

> I'm not yet a K8s expert enough to explain all the details here, but
>   fundamentally it's perfectly possible to run Prometheus outside of the
>   cluster (and required for things like redundant cross-cluster
>   meta-monitoring). Cf. the `in_cluster` config option in
>   http://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#kubernetes-sd-configurations-kubernetes_sd_config
>   . You need to jump through certificate hoops if you run it outside.

So, I made a simple configuration

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes'

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      -
        # The API server addresses. In a cluster this will normally be
        # `https://kubernetes.default.svc`. Supports multiple HA API servers.
        api_servers:
          - https://xxx.xx.xx.xx

        # Run in cluster. This will use the automounted CA certificate and bearer
        # token file at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ in the pod.
        in_cluster: false

        # Optional HTTP basic authentication information.
        basic_auth:
        username: prometheus
        password: secret

        # Retry interval between watches if they disconnect.
        retry_interval: 5s
```

Getting `unknown fields in kubernetes_sd_config: api_servers, in_cluster, retry_interval"` or some other indentation errors

In [sample configuration](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml), they mentioned `ca_file:`. How to get that certificate file from K8s or is there any way to specify K8s `config` file(~/.kube/config)

Comment: Which Prometheus version are you using? This looks similar https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2147

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By digging though the source code I figured out, that Prometheus always uses the in cluster config, if no `api_server` is provided in the config  ([`discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go#L90-L96`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/099df0c/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go#L90-L96)).

Somehow the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#<kubernetes_sd_config) don't say anything about the Kubernetes configuration parameters, but the source code does ([`config/config.go#L1026-L1037`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/099df0c5f00c45c007a9779a2e4ab51cf4d076bf/config/config.go#L1026-L1037)). Therefore there is not list named `api_servers`, but a single parameter named `api_server`.

So your config should look like this (untested):

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes'

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      -
        # The API server addresses. In a cluster this will normally be
        # `https://kubernetes.default.svc`. Supports multiple HA API servers.
        api_server: https://xxx.xx.xx.xx

        # Optional HTTP basic authentication information.
        basic_auth:
          username: prometheus
          password: secret

        # specify the CA
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /path/to/ca.crt
          ## If the actual CA file isn't available you need to disable verification:
          # insecure_skip_verify: true
```

I don't know where the `retry_interval` parameter comes from, but AFAIK this isn't a Kubernetes config parameter and it's also not part of the Prometheus config.

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply. I placed `role` in your configuration and ran. Getting `ERRO[0038] github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:209: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/pods?resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority  component="kube_client_runtime" source="kubernetes.go:76"`

Comment: In this case you have to specify the CA certificate. I updated the answer. How to retrieve that file depends on your cluster setup. If the setup isn't available, you can disable the check via [`insecure_skip_verify`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/099df0c5f00c45c007a9779a2e4ab51cf4d076bf/config/config.go#L460).

Answer (score 1):

With help of @svenwltr answer I have create docker image which we can launch in K8s cluster. Check my [repo](https://github.com/veerendra2/prometheus-server)

Answer (score 0):

> How to retrieve that file depends on your cluster setup
>
> How to get that certificate file from K8s

By default, kubernetes stores the client CA certificate file at `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt` and also at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` in a ConfigMap used by `kubeconfig`.