# How to discover pods for prometheus to scrape

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to follow https://burhan.io/flask-application-monitoring-with-prometheus/ and make my pods discovered by Prometheus but I am not having any luck.  Could someone see what I am doing wrong or debug it?

First to make sure my app is configured right...I configured it directly and saw the metrics in Prometheus.

```
- job_name: 'myapp'
        scheme: http
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['172.17.0.7:9090']
```

Next, I tried to do the discovery. This is how the deployment looks

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp 
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
...
```

and this is the prometheus config

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
        scheme: http
        metrics_path: /metrics
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
          regex: myapp
          action: keep
```

but I don't see any metrics in Prometheus or any mention of `myapp` in Prometheus debug log. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I see that you didn't define `- api_server: 'https://kubernetes'`. Make sure you define api-server in `kubernetes_sd_config`. Prometheus auto discovers services via api-server.

- Please refer my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682158/prometheus-auto-discovery-k8s)
- Sample configuration in my    repo [here](https://github.com/veerendra2/prometheus-k8s-monitoring/blob/master/prometheus-configmap.yml)
- Prometheus `kubernetes_sd_config` docs here

Answer (score 2):

My mistake. role had to be `pod` instead of `node` in the config.